# Morse function on torus and real projective plane.

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

I was considering following problem.

Let us have a torus $T^2$ and real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Let $f: T^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and  $g: \mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Morse functions. Proof that $f$ and $g$ have at least one saddle point. Find minimal number of saddle points of $f$ and $g$.

So I know that $f$ and $g$ have at least two critical points, because torus and projective plane are compact. Moreover those points are non-degenerate. I should probably use two dimentional square model of those manifolds, but to be honest, I don't know what to do next. I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the relation between critical points of Morse functions and the Euler Characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_inequalities)?

Comment: Now I do. We have $\chi_{T^2} = 0$ and $\chi_{\mathbb{R}P^2} = 1$ and Euler characteristic of compact manifold $M$ can be written as $\chi_M = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i N_{f,i}$, where $N_{f,i}$ is number of critical points of index $i$ and $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is Morse function. So every non-constatnt continous function from compact manifold has at least two critical point. For Torus we can find function with one point with index 1 and one with index 2. Then $(-1)^2 1+(-1)^11=0$. For projective plane we need three points 2 with index 2 and one with index 1. Then $(-1)^2 2+(-1)^11=1.$ Am I correct?

Comment: Not quite; the indices you've listed aren't possible. You can't determine the indices from $\chi$ alone (since there are many possibilities) but you don't need to; all you need to do is establish a lower bound on the number of critical points of index 1.